# Как вынести voluptuous.Schema в конфиг файл?

Tags: python, json, api

Вопрос такой: возможно ли вынести построенную схему в отдельный конфиг файл?

пример схемы:

```
Schema({
        Required('Calculation'): Any(None, All(str, Length(min=1))),
        Required('IsExcluded'): Boolean(),
        Required('CreateDate'): Any(None, All(str, Length(min=1))),
        Required('CreateUserName'): Any(None, All(str, Length(min=1))),
        Required('CreateUserEmail'): Any(None, All(str, Length(min=1))),
        Required('UpdateDate'): Any(None, All(str, Length(min=1))),
        Required('UpdateUserName'): Any(None, All(str, Length(min=1))),
        Required('UpdateUserEmail'): Any(None, All(str, Length(min=1))),
        Required('Id'): Any(None, All(str, Length(min=1)))
    })
```

Хотелось бы иметь быстрый доступ к смене схемы из конфиг файла проекта. В первую очередь хочется узнать возможно ли это, если да, то есть ли примеры?
Единственное что меня смущает - значения напротив полей, на сколько я понимаю, объекты:

```
from voluptuous import Schema, Required, Length, All, Boolean, Any, MultipleInvalid
```

Comment: Опишите, что имеете ввиду под конфиг-файлом? Какой юз-кейс "смены" схемы из конфиг файла? В зависимости от чего вам нужно менять схему? И почему вы считаете импорты - проблемой?

Comment: @gore, как итог - я вопспользовался yaml файлом (он выступил в роли конфиг файла) и сделал скрипт настраивающий схему исходя из описанной структуры. юз-кейс - настройка схемы без вмешательства в код. Проблема с импортом ушла.